# Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 2017 ( Community edition ) + Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 2017 ( Community edition ) + Unity .

In the Unity tutorials, you should be able to open the Unity reference documents by highlighting a Unity property in Visual Studio and hitting the Cmd + single quotation mark ( Cmd + ' ) to open the Unity reference documentation.
This does not happen automatically. How do you set this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortcut you mention only works in MonoDevelop I think. In Visual Studio 2015, the shortcut is :

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> ; then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>

If it does not work, make sure Visual Studio is correctly specified in Unity :

> Edit > Preferences > External Tools

---

Also, make sure Visual Studio is "attached to" Unity. (Do not click the button with the green "Play" arrow, but open the drop down menu at the right side of the button)

[image]

---

Lastly, make sure you have the VS tools for Unity (should be shipped with Visual Studio 2015 and 2017)

---

In Visual Studio, if you go to :

Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard, you should be able to find `Help.UnityAPIReference` in the list of shortcuts

Comment: A perfect answer. Thank you Hellium. The shortcut Ctrl + Alt + M; then Ctrl + H opens up the Unity documentation.